# /etc/hosts configuration error , ping not working

Tags: localhost, hostname, etc, kerberos

I am newbie to ubuntu plus kerberos , trying to configure kerberos in my vm ubuntu by i am not able to pass the step 2 in configuring hosts .below are the files. i am in the process of learning so please help .

my problem is when ping localhost i am getting response but when i ping monarch or krb1 i am getting error .

```
hguna@ubuntu:~$ ping -c1 localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.034/0.034/0.000 ms


   hguna@ubuntu:~$ ping -c1 monarch
    PING ubuntu.spinlock.hr (192.168.7.12) 56(84) bytes of data.

    --- ubuntu.spinlock.hr ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

my etc/hosts looks like below

127.0.0.1 localhost

192.168.7.12 ubuntu.spinlock.hr ubuntu krb1.spinlock.hr krb1 monarch.spinlock.hr monarch

my etc/hostname look like below

ubuntu

please helpe me as to where i am doing wrong

note - Both the kerberos server and the client will be installed on the same machine. However, to differentiate between client and server roles, the client will be referred to as monarch.spinlock.hr and the server as krb1.spinlock.hr. in the etc/hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Your file `/etcc/hosts` is just fine. The fact that after the command

ping -c1 **monarch**

You see:

PING ubuntu.spinlock.hr (**192.168.7.12**) 56(84) bytes of data.

means that your system can resolve host name monarch to the IP address you told it to.

It seems that other network problems / misconfiguration prevents you from pinging that host.

To start with try `ping 192.168.7.12` and if it fails try to track that error down.

Comment: i tried below is the info i am getting in the terminal  ping 192.168.7.12
PING 192.168.7.12 (192.168.7.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
        

^C
--- 192.168.7.12 ping statistics ---
73 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 72387ms

Comment: is there anything as to how to narrow down this . is there any specific log that i could peek into . please let me know